# Majesty 2, how to dissolve a heroes party

Tags: majesty-2

I would like to add new members to an existing heroes party when a hero of this party dies. Or kick out members of an existing party. Is this possible? Can I dissolve / delete / cancel a party completly?

Comment: Answres don't belong in the question.  This is strictly for your question.

Comment: I did not put an answer to my question, but used more words for the question. To improve the ability of google to find this questions. Dissolve is harder to understand than delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From both the Gamefaqs forums and the official forums, here is the way of disbanding your party:

> Go to the party list click on the star for that party and then there
>   is an option to disband in the box at the bottom of the screen.

It seems though that it is not possible to dismiss only 1 heroe: you have to disband the party completely.

Sources:

- [Gamefaqs forums](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/945877-majesty-2-the-fantasy-kingdom-sim/53192568)
- [Paradox Interactive forums](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/partys-over-how-to-disband.435218/)